# Splitting an intersection of cylinders into idential solids

Tags: geometry

I'm designing some parametric pipe fittings in various CAD software. To aid in 3D printing I've designed a single part that can be print twice and joined with glue:

[Half of a 60 degree pipe fitting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rQYL.jpg)

For two pipes I can easily describe an ellipse. However, now I'm curious if this can be done for 3 or more pipes at arbitrary angles? And what kind of resources could I study to learn how to describe this?

To phrase the question succinctly:

Can three or more pipes/cylinders be joined at arbitrary angles, then split apart into three identical solids? If so, how can that shape be described?

Comment: The number of identical pieces will depend on the overall symmetry of the final object. For pipes in a plane, this will generally be two regardless of the number of pipes, but could be as many as $n$ for $n$ pipes with adjacent angles equal. For pipes in space, the idea is the same, but the details more complicated, because polyhedra are in some senses more complicated than polygons.